# displaying questions twice

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

can anyone review this code tell me what's wrong in it? I don't understand why it is displaying questions two times.

here is the code to display questions based on its questiontype, I mean it will look into question folder for matching questiontype template and then display it with question.
this is the code to show survey's questions.

```
<cfoutput>
 <cfset step = 0 />
 <form class="form form-horizontal" action="#buildUrl(action='survey.savesurveyresults',querystring='surveyId=#rc.surveyid#')#" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="fksurveyid" value="#rc.surveyId#">
  <input type="hidden" name="fkquestionid" value="#rc.questions.id#"> 
  <fieldset> 
   <cfloop query="rc.questions">
    <cfset step ++ />
    <cfset answer = "" />
    <cfmodule template="../question/#rc.questions.template#/display.cfm" step="#step#" question="#rc.questions.question#" template1="#rc.questions.template#"  fkquestionid="#rc.questions.id#" answer="#answer#" required="#rc.questions.required#" result="result#step#"/>
   </cfloop>

   <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit answers</button>
   </div>  
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</cfoutput>
```

this is my display.cfm to view question and its questiontype like truefalse or yes or no.

```
<cfparam name="attributes.yesno" default="false">
 <cfoutput>
  <p>#attributes.step#) #attributes.question# <cfif attributes.required EQ 1><strong>*    </strong></cfif></p>
  <div class="answers">
   <cfif attributes.yesno>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="yes"<cfif attributes.answer is "yes">Checked</cfif>><label for="truefalse">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="no"<cfif attributes.answer is "No">Checked</cfif>><label for="truefalse">No</label>        
   <cfelse>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="true"<cfif attributes.answer is "true">Checked</cfif>><label for="truefalse">True</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="False"<cfif attributes.answer is "False">Checked</cfif>><label for="truefalse">False</label> 
   </cfif>
  </div>
</cfoutput>
```

here is the query to list question's records.

```
<cfquery name="list">
SELECT
questions.id,
questions.question,
questions.rank,
questions.required,
questiontypes.name as questiontype,
questiontypes.template as template,
surveys.name as surveysname,
surveys.thankyoumsg as thankyoumsg
FROM questions
 INNER JOIN questiontypes ON questions.fkquestiontypeid = questiontypes.id
 INNER JOIN surveys ON questions.fksurveyid = surveys.id
WHERE questions.fksurveyid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bigint" value="#arguments.surveyid#">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: You are looping over your query `questions`.  How many records is that returning?  I suspect 2.

Comment: yeah i am looping over the query, exactly it is returning 2 though i have only one record in question table.

Comment: So is that your problem or is it displaying both questions twice?

Comment: I have only one question in my questions table but its returning two times the same question.

Comment: if your query is returning 2 records and it should only be returning one then the issue is somewhere with your query, not the code you posted

Comment: So it sounds like it is the query that is incorrect, right?  If so, can you show us your query code?

Comment: i have updated the my question.

Comment: An important note to remember when using the `<cfmodule>` tag is that if you include an ending `</cfmodule>` tag it will call the module twice; once after the initial tag and then again with the closing tag. Even though you have not specified the closing tag as `</cfmodule>` you are actually specifying one by ending your `<cfmodule>` tag with ` />`.  This has gotten me before.  See the [docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1912c-7fce.html).

Comment: it looks like one of your 3 tables either has a duplicate row is you need to add an additional join to filter out an extra record

Comment: Thanks Miguel the problem is in closing cfmodule tag.

Comment: Yep.  That has gotten me before too.

Comment: I would like to ask you one more question if you don't mind, as you know i am displaying the questions in this way but i unable to figure out how should i have to collect the answers, like when users checked the radio on true or false. will you please let me know how should i have to collect answers.

Comment: Please ask as a new question so it does not dilute this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something that has bitten me a couple of times. I've always been pretty big on closing tags. But this is a situation where it will hurt. And be hard to debug if you don't understand the behavior of cfmodule. As the post above mine states, if you close the cfmodule tag, it will execute twice. This is because it's treated the same as a custom tag. There may be situations where you want to process part of the tag when it's first run and the rest after it's complete. You can access the ExecutionMode in the thisTag scope of the cfmodule page. With no closing tag, it's simply run in the thisTag.ExecutionMode = Start mode. If you close it, it runs the tag again in the End mode. If you aren't doing anything with the ExecutionMode inside the cfmodule's code, the whole thing will simply run again. This behavior is part of the reason that cfmodule can be so powerful.

Answer (score 6):

When using the `<cfmodule>` tag you need to remember that ColdFusion will call that tag twice if you include an ending `</cfmodule>` tag **OR** if you close the opening tag like so `<cfmodule ... />`.

As stated on the [cfmodule documentation page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1912c-7fce.html):

> If you specify an end tag to cfmodule, ColdFusion calls your custom tag as if it had both a start and an end tag. For more information, see Handling end tags in the Developing ColdFusion Applications.

[Handling end tags in the Developing ColdFusion Applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0b2e1-7ff0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d8f)

In order to avoid this functionality do not close your `<cfmodule>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, i must have not to close the cfmodule tag like `<cfmodule />`.